# how do i make one line larger (or a different color) in a multi-line ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make one line in my plot ("actual") bolder than the rest. This is the code I've been using but its not making a difference:

```r
actpred_melt %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Week.of.reporting, n, col = DF_cases)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(10, 1, 1, 1, 1)) +  
  facet_grid(.~year, scales = "free_y") +
  ylab("DF cases") +  
  xlab("wk")
```

I've also tried this:

```r
actpred_melt %>%
  ggplot(aes(Week.of.reporting, n, col = DF_cases), size = ifelse(DF_cases == "actual",5,2)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(.~year, scales = "free_y") +
  ylab("DF cases") +
  xlab("wk")
```

Plot below

[image]

a subset of my data:

```
structure(list(year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), Week.of.reporting = 1:10, DF_cases = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("actual", "pred"
), class = "factor"), n = c(119, 103, 96, 99, 53, 91, 94, 101, 
106, 132)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general method `ggplot2` uses (within `aes`) for size, group, color, etc is to determine the group they are in. If you want the *value* to be used *literally*, then you can use either `I(.)` or `scale_._identity()`, as in

```r
### not right
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, size = z, group = z)) + geom_line()
```

[image: ggplot2 with faulty "size"]

```r
### correct, either one works
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, size = I(z), group = z)) + geom_line()
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, size = z, group = z)) + geom_line() + scale_size_identity()
```

[image: ggplot2, size as literal value]

---

In your case, you are (also) assigning `size=` *outside* of `aes(...)`. For perspective, attributes assigned *within* `aes(...)` are dynamic to the data, things *outside* `aes(...)` are typically static. Change your plot to one of:

```r
actpred_melt %>%
  ggplot(aes(Week.of.reporting, n, col = DF_cases, size = I(ifelse(DF_cases == "actual",5,2)))) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(.~year, scales = "free_y") +
  ylab("DF cases") +
  xlab("wk") 

actpred_melt %>%
  ggplot(aes(Week.of.reporting, n, col = DF_cases, size = ifelse(DF_cases == "actual",5,2))) +
  scale_size_identity() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(.~year, scales = "free_y") +
  ylab("DF cases") +
  xlab("wk")
```

Comment: Could you clarify your answer based on my code. I'm a little confused as to how to apply your suggestion to my own example so that only the line for "actual" changes.

Comment: (1) It's `color=`, not `col=`. (2) Replace `size=ifelse(...)` with `size=I(ifelse(...))`.

Comment: So I tried this code:`ggplot(aes(Week.of.reporting, n, color = DF_cases), size = I(ifelse(DF_cases == "actual",5,2))) +
  geom_line()` but still no change to the plot.

Comment: With my data, things work fine. Perhaps you can share yours? `dput(...)` is good, `tibble(...)` is good too.

Comment: Is `DF_cases` a frame of its own, or a column within `Week.of.reporting`?

Comment: I made edits to my post to include a subset of my data.

Comment: See my edit, your latest issue was an `aes(...), size=` problem (vice `aes(..., size=)`).

Comment: How can I apply this code to also change the color?

Comment: *"change the color"* ... similarly, `aes(...), color="green"` changes all colors, regardless; `aes(..., color=z)` varies the color by the unique values of `z` (if discrete/integer) or on a gradient (if continuous, not integer/char/logical).

Comment: So I want to make the same line "actual" black. I tried this `ggplot(aes(Week.of.reporting, n, col = DF_cases, color = I(DF_cases == "actual, "black"), size = I(ifelse(DF_cases == "actual",1,0.5))))` but its giving me an error.

Comment: `I(DF_cases == "actual, "black")` makes no sense, is there supposed to be an `if_else` and a "no" option?

Comment: Perhaps `color = I(if_else(DF_cases == "actual", "black", "blue"))`?

Comment: But the other lines have to be different colors so if_else won't work. I just want the one line to be black and the others to be default